# LINQ: How to null out properties in a projection?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

The title is pretty terrible, so let me try to explain in code. I have a an entity called `Change` and it has a collection of `ChangeDetail` entities. I want to project a collection of `Change` entities to a DTO called `ChangeListItem`. I've been messing around with LINQPad and I actually have the projection done and working as I want, but what I can't get to work is to null out all `ChangeListItem`s in the group except for the first one. Here's my code:

**Change** class

```
public class Change : {
    public DateTime ChangedDateTime { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<ChangeDetail> Details { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    public Change() {
        this.Details = new List<ChangeDetail>();
    }
}
```

**ChangeDetail** class

```
public class ChangeDetail {
    public string Details { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    public int ChangeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Change Change { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

My LINQPad attempt

```
var changes =
    Changes
        .SelectMany(c => c.Details)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.Change.ChangedDateTime)
        .Select(c => new ChangeListItem
        {
            ChangedDateTime = c.Change.ChangedDateTime,
            Details = c.Details
        })
        .GroupBy(c => c.ChangedDateTime)
        .ForEach(g =>
        {
            g
                .Skip(1)
                .ForEach(c =>
                {
                    c.ChangedDateTime = null;
                });
        });
```

When I dump that into the results pane I still get a collection of groups of `ChangeListItem`, but the `ChangedDateTime` property is still filled out. I'm sure I'm missing a reassignment somewhere along the way, even though I thought the one I'm doing should be good enough. How can I get it to what I want?

I want to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

**Update** As requested here's the code for the `ForEach` extension:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions {
    public static IQueryable<T> ForEach<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Action<T> action) {
        if (source == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        if (action == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }

        foreach (T t in source) {
            action(t);
        }

        return source.AsQueryable<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're treating a LINQ *query* as though it were a *collection*. I assume your `ForEach` extension looks like this:

```
foreach(var item in source)
{
    SideEffect(item);
}

return source;
```

Here the results of the query are enumerated once, and each of its result items is mutated. But then when when you enumerate the query again, its results are *recreated* from scratch; consequently the mutations are 'lost'.

In theory, it would be possible to include some strategic `ToList()` calls into your code to get the desired effect. But this isn't in the spirit of LINQ.  Don't mix LINQ and side-effects. If you want to conditionally project some items and leave others untouched, do it this way:

```
changeGroup.Select( (c, index) => index == 0 ? c : new ChangeListItem 
                    { 
                        ChangedDateTime = null,
                        Details = c.Details
                    } );
```

Btw, you may need to call `AsEnumerable()` before you perform this transformation as I don't think LINQ to Entities supports the overload of `Select` that includes the item index (can't recall off-hand, though).

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but without knowing the return type of the `ForEach` extension there may be an alternative explanation. The OP needs to provide the signature (and semantics of `ForEach`).

Comment: **Enigmativity**, I've updated my post with the extension code. **Ani**, I assume you're correct, I'm just confused on where to make the change you're suggesting in my code.

Comment: Try this for a start: 
 `.GroupBy(c => c.ChangedDateTime).AsEnumerable().Select(changeGroup => changeGroup.Select( ... ).ToList())`

This is only to help you understand; you can definitely express what you want better.

Comment: @Ani, that did it, thanks! I added a `.SelectMany(g => g)` at the end so it flattened into a single collection, and it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!